# RSA Decryption Issue C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, monodevelop

RSA Decryption Issue

I am having problems with a C# RSA program. It is not decrypting properly. When I assign `d =(e^-1)%phiN`, and then apply d to my ciphertext it comes up with ridiculous decimal answers. It should come up with a whole number. I think it is a problem with my math. Do you have any advice? 
If you need details or the rest of the code, please ask.
Also, is there a padding scheme I could use to make this code better? Right now this code is vulnerable to frequency analysis.

```
protected void decryptRSA(object sender, EventArgs ev)

{
        double p = (double)Convert.ToInt64(P.Text);//I use 123 for testing
        double q = (double)Convert.ToInt64(Q.Text);//127
        double e = (double)Convert.ToInt64(E.Text);//133
        double phiN = (p-1)*(q-1);
        double n = p*q;
        double d = Math.Pow(e, -1D);
        d = d%phiN;

        string cipherStr = outputBuffer.Text;
        double[] cipherTextDouble = new double[100];
        string[]plainText = new string[cipherTextDouble.Length];

        cipherTextDouble = parser(cipherStr, 'D');
     for(int slot = 0; slot<cipherTextDouble.Length; slot++)
        {
    cipherTextDouble[slot] = (double)(Math.Pow((double)cipherTextDouble[slot],(double)d)%n);
        }
        for(int slot = 0; slot<cipherTextDouble.Length; slot++)
        {
            inputBuffer.Text += Convert.ToChar(cipherTextDouble[slot]) + ' ';//the spot were it dies
//it doesn't like to convert from a decimal like 1.75 to a char. Of course I should never get a decimal like 1.75, which is the problem
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calculating the exponent correctly. You need to find a number `d` such that `ed = 1 (mod phi)` i.e. the inverse of `e (mod phi)`. This is not the same as calculating the inverse of e in the reals which is what `double d = Math.Pow(e, -1D);` calculates, and then doing the mod operation. This is the reason that you end up with a decimal number (in this case 1/133 ~ 0.007 and 1/133 % 15372 still = 0.007 since `%` is actually a 'remainder' operator in C# and not an integer modulus (otherwise it wouldn't work on a double anyway)).

You need to use the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the inverse mod phi.

EDIT: GregS correctly points out that for a computer implementation you probably want to use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) instead to find the modular inverse in a single pass. This is what is usually done computationally. You can do it with the Euclidean algorithm (usually by hand) but it's a waste of time.

Comment: The *extended* euclidean algorithm.